# Azure Cognitive Face throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to make a Xamarin app that will recognize faces on pictures taken by camera. Somehow, this part of the code throws a NullReferenceException

```
using (Stream imageFileStream = new MemoryStream(a))
{
    imageFileStream.Position = 0;
    var result = await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(imageFileStream);

    if (result != null)
        await BlobStorageService.SaveBlockBlob("photos", a, Entry1.Text);
}
```

Where "a" is a byte[] of the picture

I wonder how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Exeption.SystemStack shows that the exception is inside the var result...

Comment: Are you sure `faceServiceClient` is not null?

Comment: To extend what @G.hakim mentioned, can you show how you create `faceServiceClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that Microsoft stopped supporting Project Oxford (or something like that), so I used Azure.Cognitive.Vision.Face instead :\